# How to Join Skype for Business (Lync) Meetings as a Guest using MAC?

Tags: macos, skype, skype-for-business

I received a Skype for business meeting (meet.lync.com) request and I don't have a business account in Skype. My operating system is Mac. I clicked on the meeting and a new opened which said your meeting is open in another window and nothing really happened.

[Join Meeting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqzqY.png)

Can someone suggest how to join a Skype business meeting from Mac OS as a guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install SkypeMeetingsapp.dmg from the following link in in MAC.

https://az801095.vo.msecnd.net/prod/LWA/plugins/mac/SkypeMeetingsApp.dmg

After installing when you click on the Join Meeting link you will get a pop up as given below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4iGc.png)

Now you can click Open and you can provide your name and click to join the meeting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VfPA.png)